# How to implement proxy on Next.js?

Tags: javascript, typescript, next.js

I have a problem with implementing proxy on Next.js. I use react-query to fetch data from backend that is served from a different port (8000).

My understanding is that when I make a request to `http://localhost:3000/api/v1/users`, Next.js should automatically redirect it to `http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/v1/users`. However, it doesn't seem to be working.

Can anyone explain how Next.js proxy works and how to fix this issue?

Next.js: 13
React-query: 4.29.25

**next.config.js**

```js
/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */
const nextConfig = {
    rewrites:{
    source: "/api/:path*",
    destination: "http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/:path*",
  },
};

module.exports = nextConfig;
```

**urls.ts**

```js
const BASE_BACKEND_V1 = window.location.origin + '/api/v1';

const urls = {
    base_backend: {
        users: `${BASE_BACKEND_V1}/users`,
                // other endpoints
    },
};

export default urls;
```

**api.ts**

```
import { useMutation, useQuery } from '@tanstack/react-query';
import urls from '../urls';

export const useUsersQuery(props = {}) => {
    const url = url.base_backend.users;
    const urlParamed = new URL(url);
    
    if (props.name) urlParamed.searchParams.append('name', props.name);
    
    return useQuery(
        ['useUsersQuery', ...Object.values(props)],
    async () => fetchWithAuth<Paginated<Excelsheet>>(urlParamed.href),
    { keepPreviousData: false },
    );
}
```

Before I used `const BASE_BACKEND_V1 = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000' + '/api/v1';` but I need a solution that works with proxy instead.

Comment: Quick solution is not to use `window.location.origin +` part. Just use the rest part i.e. `/api/v1`

Comment: I've added `window.location.origin` so that when `new URL(url)` works, without a base and using just relative path it doesn't work.